# What does ここは refer to in this context: じゃここは俺から名乗らせていただこう。

Tags: meaning

Watching / studying from an anime at the moment and I came across the following sentence.

> じゃ**ここは**俺から名乗らせていただこう。

Am I right in my thinking that ここ in this context is referring to 個々?
So essentially saying something like:

> "OK, let's introduce ourselves one-by-one starting with me."

I've never really encountered 個々 before in a sentence so I'm not sure if I am interpreting its usage correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ここ is "here" and it refers to the current situation/issue at hand. This ここは can be translated like "in this case", "regarding this (issue)", "this is where (something/someone comes into play)", or simply "well then".

個々 is not relevant. Note that 個々 is usually written in kanji, and "individually" or "one by one" is 個々**に**, not 個々は.

Comment: I originally thought it was ここ here, but then was thrown off by the は. Do you have any example sentences showing more of the ここは used with the meaning you explained?

Comment: @Ryan ここは俺に任せて先に行け ("I'll take care of this one, you go ahead!"), ここはあなたの魔法の出番ですね ("This is where your magic comes into play"), ここは譲れません ("This time, it's not negotiable"), etc.